# How do I count value of string Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, count

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class countnumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("input string:");
            String[] array = br.readLine().split("\\D+");
            String newtext = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){

                //int sum = 0;
                //for (int e : array) sum += e;
                //System.out.println(sum);
                // This part particulary works for Integer type arrays... i guess
            }

            System.out.println("result:");
            System.out.print(newtext);
        }       
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
        }
    }
}
```

Hello.

I'm facing the problem where I have to count and sum the numbers in array, which also contains text and other symbols. Could anyone provide some hints how to do that? Sample of current program is given above.

Comment: First of all, read your code. What type of data does your `array` contain?

Comment: What kind of value does your array like to have ?

Comment: I am assuming this is homework. Did you learn any method that converts a string with digits in it into a number? Do you think such a method can be applied in this exercise? How?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Does it matter if a homework or not? Since when we judge questions based on work or school?

Comment: I hope that I got the questions right:
The array contains the date form keyboard e.g. 1231posdpo'~#@

Yes, it is my homework, but I want to understand how to do it.

Comment: @Dāgs Putniņš Would you give us sample inputs?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis It matters not because homework is not OK for StackOverflow. It matters because homework is supposed to teach the person how to program, so I believe we shouldn't spoon-feed an answer to the question, but rather try to get the student to solve it himself.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I disagree, because homeworks should be tricky and not easily to be solved sometimes. Depends on your skill. StackOverflow is a place to help anyone no matters the purpose of question. Answering based on these circumstances is very backward.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a utiliy method like the following

```
public boolean isNumeric(String str){
    try{
        Double.parseDouble(str);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

And in your main code

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
    if (isNumeric(array[i])) sum+= Double.parseDouble(array[i]);
}
```

---

I'm using a `double` to be sure but you can replace it with `int`, the logic stays the same

Comment: Most of inputs won't pass this code. He edited his input. Check it out.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis How wont his inputs pass the code?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis I can not find any edit and you're not answering the question...

Comment: Sorry, I mean a comment. My mistake.. His input would be "1231posdpo'~#@" as String .. and he wants to sum numbers in that String resulting 1+2+3+1=7 .. I assume that

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Note that the first thing the OP does is split the input using the delimiter `"\\D+"` which means the array will only contain strings of digits.

Answer (score 0):

You've already answered part of your question yourself (how to sum integers of array). Your real question is so simple that it takes only three words to get answer from google. I will help you: [PARSE INTEGER STRING](https://www.google.lt/?gws_rd=ssl#q=parse+integer+string) . If you would click on first result, read first answer (it has 2166 votes up) you would save stackowerflow's HDD space as well as my time that I spent to write this answer.